# how to run php script from batch file

Tags: php, mysql, batch-file, windows-services

I have used this article [php script](http://www.akchauhan.com/create-windows-service-to-schedule-php-script-execution/comment-page-1/#comment-972982) which named upload_.php and i have successfully developed a windows service in C# which is running fine. Now in theory the service will run every hour and execute a batch file (task.bat). if i run the upload_php file directly it works fine now i think the problem is in task.bat file. here is my code

**Task.bat Code**

```
@echo off
cd\
set path=C:\xampp\php;
cd "C:\xampp\htdocs"
php import.php
exit
```

When service runs it execute task.bat file but php script dont execute. what is wrong with my code????

Comment: You should be seeing an error message. (@Sverri Apache shouldn't be needed here)

Comment: Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php (but you seem to be doing everything right)

Comment: I have no idea about MS-Windows, but doesn't it (whyever) require all executables to be called *.exe? So `php.exe` in this case instead of just `php`?

Comment: is space missing first cd so rather than cd\ you need cd \?  When you run the batch file by hand do you see error message?  try running .bat file in a console window and remove the echo off so you can see what happens then let us know.

Comment: i'm able to see that you are running import.php in your tasks.bat instead upload_.php.. am i right ?

Comment: this worked for me 
@echo OFF
"D:\xampp\php\php.exe" D:\xampp\htdocs\upload_.php %*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this worked for me although im not a php developer a colleague helped me

```
@echo OFF
"D:\xampp\php\php.exe" D:\xampp\htdocs\upload_.php %*
```

Comment: So the problem was that your path and change directory were both specifying the wrong drive letter because your php was installed on the D: drive and not the C: drive?  And you were specifying arguments to the .bat file which needed to be provided to the php script and your use of the php command was not providing those?