# Error - to run php file using batch file

Tags: php, batch-file, cmd

I am using a windows machine.
I want to run a php file which is on W-Drive (network drive) and my bat file is on desktop.
I don't understand why but somehow it is not executing my php file.
My code looks like this

```
@echo call to php script
@echo OFF
"D:\xampp\php\php" W:\Automation\Task\csv-file\delete-special-chars.php %*
timeout /t 60
pause
```

It does not show errors either 
Took reference from [how to run php script from batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750523/how-to-run-php-script-from-batch-file)

Any suggestion where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Also when I run php script which will delete special characters from browser I first get this error 
`Notice: iconv(): Detected an incomplete multibyte character in input string in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Wdrive/Automation/Task/csv-file/delete-special-chars.php on line 17` and then if i refresh again it execute without error.

My php scipt looks like this

```
<?php

foreach (glob("*.csv") as $file) 
{
    $contents = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    $csvRows = array_map('str_getcsv', $contents);

    $output_array = array();

    foreach($csvRows as $row) 
    {
        // echo $row[0] . "\n"; // Will output  data contained in the first column

        $input = $row[0]; // original text

        $output = iconv("utf-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $input);

        $output_array[] =  preg_replace("/^'|[^A-Za-z0-9\s-]|'$/", '', $output); // lets remove utf-8 special characters except blank spaces

        // echo $output; // Results in: Foo Bar Zacarias ASABAD Ferreira
    }

    file_put_contents($file, implode("\n", $output_array));
}
?>
```

Please suggest me where am I going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot the extension `.exe`

So change it to this:

```
"D:\xampp\php\php.exe"
```

Otherwise try this:

```
start "Start PHP" "D:\xampp\php\php.exe" -f delete-special-chars.php
```

EDIT:

If you want to change something in a `file` the `php` script get's executed from the `batch` file `location` so you have to `cd` to the `php` script like this:

```
cd W:\Automation\Task\csv-file
```

So with this your php script gets executed from the php script location

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65251/discussion-between-deep-kataria-and-rizier123).

Comment: Sorted :D Thanks to show me the issue. I have edited the answer

Comment: @deepkataria So it works now? what was the key to the solution?

Comment: `W:` -this will go in w drive

`cd Automation\Task\csv-file` this will go to my folder where php script resides
`start "Start PHP" "D:\xampp\php\php.exe" -f delete-special-chars.php %*` this will run my php script

Comment: @deepkataria Nice that you got the solution! (BTW: 1. an upvote would be nice :D for me effort(you don't have to!) 2. you can accept your own answer if you want)

Comment: It is not allowing me to accept an answer...dont know the what's the issue..may be after two days i can accept my answer thats what its telling.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo call to php script to delete all the special characters
@echo OFF
W:

cd Automation\Task\csv-file
start "Start PHP" "D:\xampp\php\php.exe" -f delete-special-chars.php %*
```